# Justify the action functional

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation

The action functionals in physics always seems [weird](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/109889/224242) to me. In this thread, I hope to formally justify them by arguing that for all kinds of dynamical systems, such magical functional exists.

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, and $M \xrightarrow{f_t} M$ is a one-parameter family of diffeomorphism, with $f_0 = 1_M$. Denote $P(M)$ by the free path space of $M$.

**Question 1.** Does there exist a function $P(M) \xrightarrow{S} \mathbb{R}$ such that

- $S(\gamma_1 \ast \gamma_2) = S(\gamma_1) + S(\gamma_2)$, where $\ast$ denotes the concatenate operator and the $\gamma_i$'s are concatenatable.
- $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \gamma} |_{\gamma_0} = 0$ for all $\gamma_0$ traced out by $f_t$ near t=0 ?

If so, how large is the solution space for such $S$?

**Question 2.** Conversely, if no $f_t$ were given, but only the $S$ was given. For a point $x \in M$, does $S$ always induce a vector $v \in T_xM$ that dictates where $x$ is moving toward?

Comment: I don't think I understand what the second property means, though I'm a bit weak in differential geometry in general.

Comment: Not every smooth dynamical system is Lagrangian.[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406411/is-the-lagrangian-a-characteristic-of-general-dynamical-systems) contains some potentially useful discussion.

Comment: @Ian I've updated it for it to be less confusing.. so in general $S$ eats a path $\gamma$ and spits out a number. The second condition just says that all the $\gamma_0$ are critical points for $S$.

Comment: @Kajelad thanks for your comment. I was aware of the Helmholtz condition.. but it seems very specific. I will have to read more before I judge. In the meanwhile, I added another question concerning the behavior of any point once an action is given.